# Select transformed submaps of nested map using specter

Tags: clojure, specter

Is there a straight-forward way to select a submap containing a transformed submap of each map-value in a nested map using specter?

An example: `cr` is a nested map,

```
{:marks {:these :values :are :omitted}, 
 :scores {:to :simplify :the :example}, 
 :results {1 {:total 8, :sums {:p1 5, :p2a 3}, :check true}, 
           2 {:total 8, :sums {:p1 9, :p2b -1}, :check false}}}
```

and from this I want to extract a map (int -> boolean) containing
for each key in `:results`, the value associated with the `:check` key,

in this case `{1 true 2 false}`

I can do it in two steps as

```
 (:results (spc/transform [:results spc/MAP-VALS] :check cr))
```

or, in the general case where the desired submap is not at the top level

```
(spc/select-one [...... :results] (spc/transform .... cr))
```

Without specter, the transformation can be expressed quite similarly as (and arguably no less clearly) as

```
(mapmap #(:check %2) (:results cr))
```

where mapmap is

```
(defn mapmap
"creates a map, by mapping f over the values in m
f is a function with two arguments, and is passed
the key and the value "
[f m]
    (reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %2 (f %2 %3) ) {} m)
)
```

I feel like I am is missing something, as I cannot express it in specter as a single navigation.
Can this query be expressed in a single `select` or `transform` using specter?

[Recursive map query using specter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889373/recursive-map-query-using-specter) seems related, but I don't quite get how recursive paths work or how to use them for the transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing piece was the `transformed` navigator:

```
(transformed path update-fn)

Navigates to a view of the current value by transforming it with the 
specified path and update-fn.
```

Which can be used in the desired one-liner

```
(spc/select-one [:results (spc/transformed [spc/MAP-VALS] :check)] cr)
==> {1 true, 2 false}
```